# Run coded ui test of wpf application in MTM with build? - interactive window

Tags: .net, unit-testing, tfsbuild, coded-ui-tests, mtm

I am trying to run coded UI test in MTM when build is triggering in TFS2015.
set up is done with test agent and test controller and created LabEnvironment. When I trigger build then build is success but test case is not executed showing below error .Enabled interactive window in test agent.

> Error calling Initialization method for test class
>   CodedUITestProject.CodedUITest1:
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestException:  To
>   run tests that interact with the desktop, you must set up the test
>   agent to run as an interactive process. For more information,  see
>   "How to: Set Up Your Test Agent to Run Tests That Interact with the
>   Desktop" (`http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=255012`) If you are
>   running the tests as part of your team build, you must also set up the
>   build age

Answer (score 0):

To run Coded UI Test in lab environment, you need to check Configure environment to run UI Test option and select a role to run UI test for lab environment in MTM.
[image]

For LabDefaltTemplate build process template, you can specify lab environment to run test. If you are using DefaultTemplate, it runs test on build agent, you need to configure build service running as Interactive process. (TFS admin console=>XAML Build Configuration=>Click properties of build service=>Run the Service as)

Comment: Yes, I have Configured same.. but showing same error.  TFS, MTM, test agent and test controller are in same machine (Local machine..)

Comment: At set up where I need to have administrative privileges..  I struggling more on this...

Comment: Is it a vNext (web-based) or XAML build? How do you run test in lab environment during the build?

Comment: thanks the response.. XAML Build.. when I checked in code it will trigger the build as part of build then coded UI test method will run. I saw video at this link " https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kewDYb6LFDc" . I guess, I installed all in same machine.. build does not refer the "test agent which I configured through test agent config tool " . It is using the agent from TFS default agent. I am not sure this could be the cause..

Comment: @Pars Do you use LabDefaultTemplate? For LabDefaltTemplate build process template, you can specify lab environment to run test. If you are using DefaultTemplate, it runs test on build agent, you need to configure build service running as Interactive process. (TFS admin console=>XAML Build Configuration=>Click properties of build service=>Run the Service as)

Comment: Hi starain, I looking help for below one.  "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39348724/last-action-on-list-item-was-not-recorded-because-the-control-does-not-have-any"

Comment: @Pars I edited my answer with a conclude, you can mark it as answer.